# Can you get the IOError that caused the IOErrorEvent?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, ioerror

In a Flash/AS3 application, you can get an [`IOErrorEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html) when a I/O operation fails.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, problem);
loader.load(new URLRequest("config.xml"));

function problem(e:IOErrorEvent)
{
    trace(e.toString());
}
```

I would like to know what failed. Is there a way to get the [`IOError`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/errors/IOError.html) from the event? The `toString()` method doesn't give us a lot of information, nor do any others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOErrorEvent **is** the error: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html

It has all the things you need:

- errorID - the reference number
- target/currentTarget - the one that dispatches it
- text
- type - the type of the error (check [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html#constantSummary) for list of IO constants)

I can't think of something else you might want to know :)

Comment: All right. Now, what I'd like to know is why it doesn't have any information about the file you're trying to load (when on projector).

Comment: Well you are using `loader.load(new URLRequest("config.xml"));`.. You want the error to contain information about the url that you don't know? :) IO_ERROR is not used only when loading files, it's used for a lot of things, so it doesn't contain information about your file (which you should know)

Comment: [Created a new question for this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060278/why-dont-ioerrorevents-contain-the-url-when-running-standalone)