# Why don't IOErrorEvents contain the URL when running standalone?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, ioerror, urlloader

Here is a simple example of an [`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html).

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://example.com/doesntexist.txt");
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent){
    textbox.text = e.toString(); // Text box on stage
});
loader.load(request);
```

This behaves weirdly.

When running from Flash or debugging from Flash, the error looks like this.

> [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://example.com/doesntexist.txt"]

But, when running as a `.swf` or an `.exe` projector, it looks like this.

> [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]

Why is this so? Is there a way to get the first result when standalone?

**EDIT:** I need to get it working as a projector.

Comment: Are you using debug player?

Comment: Got this with both Test Movie and Debug Movie.

Comment: If you right-click on the movie, do you have `Debug` option?

Comment: I only get the URL when running the movie from the Flash application, either via Test Movie (`Ctrl-Enter`) or Debug Movie (`Ctrl-Shift-Enter`). Couldn't find a `Debug` option, where is it?

Comment: Please, read carefully what I'm asking. When running the standalone .swf, if you right-click on the movie, do you have the `Debug` option in the menu?

Comment: No, I don't have that.

Comment: Well install Debug Flash Player: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html I think this should help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55132/discussion-between-pietu1998-and-andrey-popov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure about the why (probably an efficiency thing behind the scenes in flash player), here is a way to accomplish what you'd like:

You can write a custom class that extends `URLLoader` that stores the url for you.

```
package 
{
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class MyURLLoader extends URLLoader
    {
        public var request:URLRequest; //all were doing here is adding this public property and setting it when loading into the URLLoader

        public function MyURLLoader(request_:URLRequest) {
            request = request_;
            super(request);
        }

        override public function load(request_:URLRequest):void 
        {
            request = request_;
            super.load(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Then when handling your error, you can reference the URL like so:

```
var loader:MyURLLoader = new MyURLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://example.com/doesntexist.txt");

loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent){
    textbox.text = e.toString() + " URL: " + MyURLLoader(e.currentTarget).request; // Text box on stage
});
loader.load(request);
```

Comment: Are you kidding me?! :) As long as he **creates** the URLRequest, he **knows** the url..

Comment: @AndreyPopov - What if they are loading 50 things?  What about code encapsulation and re usability?  Do you know the context of this code?

Comment: In your case, the easiest solution would be to use a simple object to map loader to url, and then just get the url by using `loaders[e.target];`. Overriding such a class, for me, is an absurd.

Comment: The question is about IOErrorEvent and how to get it to trace what's needed. This is built-in in AS3 and works properly when used for proper purpose - debugging. I don't see how we came to this point to talk about encapsulating such a thing :) Anyways, I haven't said your answer is wrong, of course, it will work as you've describe, I just don't get why is this needed and why you offer such a hacked overloading solutions to something so simple (I don't want to know how he's going to get this 'trace' message, with a text box, really?!)

Comment: @AndreyPopov Well, I just looked at this and the idea of storing the request URL at the loader seems just great for me. I am using only one error function for ~10 files, so I really want to get the URL. I'll do exactly this (although with slight modifications to fit my project better).

Answer (score -1):

Install Debugger Flash Player from: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html
This will help you.

Comment: How will it help me? I can not install anything on the machine I will be running my application on; I must use a projector.

Comment: You asked how to see the full error in **standalone**. I explained it to you. Now you want to see it in exe - that's different question. There are different approaches, but all require external software like: http://demonsterdebugger.com/downloads